# Unattended run for Gatling

Tags: scala, maven, gatling

I generated a maven project for gatling using the archetype approach. When I run the Engine.scala file from eclipse I ask for input on which simulation to run.
I added the property for the simulation class using the Gatling PropertiesBuilder but it still asks for a simulation id. I want to provide all the information upfront so that when I run Engine.scala it does not prompt me for input.

Here is my code

```
val props = new GatlingPropertiesBuilder
props.dataDirectory(IDEPathHelper.dataDirectory.toString)
props.resultsDirectory(IDEPathHelper.resultsDirectory.toString)
props.bodiesDirectory(IDEPathHelper.bodiesDirectory.toString)
props.binariesDirectory(IDEPathHelper.mavenBinariesDirectory.toString)
props.simulationClass("za.co.insights.gatling.RecordedSimulation")  
props.runDescription("Testing")
props.mute()    
//props.reportsOnly("true")
//props.
//Gatling.fromArgs

Gatling.fromMap(props.build)
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this go to your gattling.conf file and set  **mute = true**

Comment: Setting mute to true in the config file or providing it as a property has no effect. It still asks for input.

Comment: No that is right . I will suggest you get it working individually in isolation and then imitate the behavior ...